# Changed github account, not able to clone repository

Tags: git, github

I just changed my github account, generated a new SSH key, synced that up with github and get `hi username, you've successfully authenticated but github doesn't provide shell access`, and changed my github config to new user info and token, but when I try to clone a private repository, I'm getting `fatal: repository not found`

What's going wrong here?

I tried to make a repository just to test it, and I got error "authentication failed". But I also looked at github after, and saw that the repository was made, but not pushed to.

Well, I chose to just delete git and start from scratch. I did sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/git.

Well, reinstalled git, and I'm still having this error. What's going on? This is pretty bad.

Comment: Are you using a GitHub client ? To go further, go to one of your local clones and write here the result of `vim .git/config`.

Comment: got it :0 see answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was I wasn't prompted to change my Keychain for github, so I had no idea I was using the old password from my other github account. Make sure to update your keychains.